# How to test Flask views that edit the database?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to write tests to cover most of the functionality of a website I am building, but I keep getting the following error while running my tests.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 291, in test_delete_post_page_li
    response = c.get('/delete_post/1', follow_redirects=True)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1006, in get
    return self.open(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/testing.py", line 227, in open
    follow_redirects=follow_redirects,
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 970, in open
    response = self.run_wsgi_app(environ.copy(), buffered=buffered)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 861, in run_wsgi_app
    rv = run_wsgi_app(self.application, environ, buffered=buffered)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 1096, in run_wsgi_app
    app_rv = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/app/blogs/views.py", line 182, in delete_post
    db_session.delete(post)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 162, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2018, in delete
    self._delete_impl(state, instance, head=True)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2030, in _delete_impl
    to_attach = self._before_attach(state, obj)
  File "/home/kody/Projects/lifeLongLearning/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2417, in _before_attach
    % (state_str(state), state.session_id, self.hash_key)
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<Post at 0x7fa75bb2ec50>' is already attached to session '19' (this is '4')
```

The tests code is:

```
class LoggedDatabaseTests(TestCase):

############################
#### setup and teardown ####
############################

def create_app(self):
    app.config.from_object('config.TestConfiguration')

    return app

# executed prior to each test
def setUp(self):
    self.engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
    self.db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                     autoflush=False,
                                     bind=self.engine))
    Base.query = self.db_session.query_property()
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)

# executed after each test
def tearDown(self):
    self.db_session.close()
    self.db_session.remove()
    self.db_session.rollback()
    Base.metadata.drop_all(self.engine)


def test_delete_post_page_li(self):

    p_cat = PostCategory(name='froots')
    self.db_session.add(p_cat)
    self.db_session.commit()

    post = Post(name='Hello', content='3fhskajlga', category_id=1, category=p_cat)
    self.db_session.add(post)
    self.db_session.commit()
    with app.test_client() as c :
        login(c, '*****', '*****')

        response = c.get('/delete_post/1', follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

    assert post not in self.db_session
```

The db_session mentioned in the test code is not the same db_session in the delete post view.

The code for the login function is:

```
def login(client, username, password):
    return client.post('/login', data=dict(
        username=username,
        password=password
    ), follow_redirects=True)
```

The login view is:

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        if check_password_hash(passwrd, form.password.data) and form.username.data == 'LLLRocks':
            session['logged_in'] = True

            return redirect(url_for('other.home'))

    # load login template
    return render_template('login.html', form=form, title='Login')
```

The delete view is:

```
#
# Delete Post
# Description:
#   This is a view that will delete a post. The id that is passed in is that of the
#   post that will be deleted.
#
@blogs.route('/delete_post/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_post(id):
    """
    Delete a post from the database
    """
    # check if user is logged in
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return redirect(url_for('other.home'))

    post = Post.query.get(id)

    db_session.delete(post)
    db_session.commit()

    db_session.close()
    db_session.remove()
    db_session.rollback()

    # redirect to the home page
    return redirect(url_for('other.home'))
```

The database.py file is below. The db_session from this file is the db_session mentioned in the delete_post view.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

# Need to connect to the new database
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://****:******@******/****', convert_unicode=True, pool_recycle=3600, pool_pre_ping=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
    # import all modules here that might define models so that
    # they will be registered properly on the metadata.  Otherwise
    # you will have to import them first before calling init_db()
    import app.models
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

One of these days I will dive deep into the documentation, but until then sorry for my ignorance. If I have missed posting any important code please tell me and I will post it right away.

Comment: You definitely do not want those db_session.remove() calls there as the post you get from the query is tied to the session. When you do the remove(), you are destroying that session and getting a new one the next time you reference db_session. What happens if you remove both of those?

Comment: I have eliminated one of the db_session.remove() from the delete view. The one I left is needed to close out the session and avoid a 'MySQL has gone away error'. The one in teardown is needed to clean out the database after each test. I updated the quest to show the new code

Comment: Is db_session the same one referenced in your tests? If so, that's the problem. Post.query is going to use current_app.db.session. Use that one in your delete view instead.

Comment: The are not the same db_session. The db_session in the delete_post view is different from the db_session in the test. In the question I have added the code from database.py where the db_session for the delete_post view is used. I have tried used current_app.db_session and current_app.db.session but I get an error like ```AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'db_session'```. From the research I did after realizing that the db_sessions are not the same, because of @DavidK.Hess suggestion, I found that I probably need to do a mock. Does that sound right

Comment: Now that I look at your setUp() code more closely, you are setting the query attribute to be based on that current value of db_session. But that will be unreferenceable later when you need to call delete(). The error messages are telling you that any object produced by a particular session must also be deleted by that session. Are you using the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension? It would normally take care of this for you such that Post.query and current_app.db.session are always referring to the same session.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess I am not using Flask-SQLAlchemy right now. I was before but over the course of fixing a 'MySQL has gone away error' I switched to using just SQLAlchemy. What fixed that error was something else I did, but I just left it as is. I think I may have to switch the app back to using Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Comment: One of the things that Flask-SQLAlchemy gives you is automatic session management between Base.query and current_app.db.session. Otherwise, the job falls to you to keep it all straight and it can get complicated like this.

Comment: I am using git, so I will go back and look at the good when I was using Flask-SQLAlchemy. Then I'll change the code to use Flask-SQLAlchemy again. Then it should work

Comment: I have switched to use Flask-SQLAlchemy and now have all my tests working. Should I close this question or answer it?

Comment: Sure, answering your own question is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to get the code working and below I will post about how I was able to get it to work.

The test code now looks like the following.

```
from app.database import db
from config import TestConfiguration
from app import create_app as c_app

class TestingWhileLoggedIn(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        app = c_app(TestConfiguration)
        return app

    # executed prior to each test
    def setUp(self):
        self.app_context = self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        db.create_all()

        login(self.client, 'LLLRocks', 'h0ngk0ng')

    # executed after each test
    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

        logout(self.client)

  def test_delete_post_page_li(self):
        p_cat = PostCategory(name='froots')

        db.session.add(p_cat)
        db.session.commit()

        post = Post(name='Hello', content='3fhskajlga', category_id=1, category=p_cat)
        db.session.add(post)
        db.session.commit()

        response = self.client.get('/delete_post/1', follow_redirects=False)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

        deleted_post = Post.query.filter_by(name='Hello').first()

        self.assertEqual(deleted_post, None)

        assert post not in db.session
```

The config file now looks like

```
import os
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

# _cwd = dirname(abspath(__file__))

_basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


TOP_LEVEL_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)

class Config(object) :
    pass

class BaseConfiguration(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False


class ProductionConfiguration(BaseConfiguration):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = '***************'
    SQLALCHEMY_POOL_PRE_PING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS = {'pool_recycle' : 3600}
    SECRET_KEY = '************'
    UPLOAD_FOLDER = TOP_LEVEL_DIR + '/app/static'


class TestConfiguration(BaseConfiguration):
    TESTING = True
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = False

    SECRET_KEY = '************'

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(_basedir, 'testing.sqlite')
```

The database.py file is as follows

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

and the create_app function being imported is

```
def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)@blogs.route('/delete_post/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_post(id):
    """
    Delete a post from the database
    """
    # check if user is logged in
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return redirect(url_for('other.home'))

    post = Post.query.get(id)
    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()

    # redirect to the home page
    return redirect(url_for('other.home'))

    from app import models

    from .blogs import blogs as blogs_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(blogs_blueprint)

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    from .other import other as other_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(other_blueprint)

    from .worksheets import worksheets as worksheets_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(worksheets_blueprint)




    @app.teardown_appcontext
    def shutdown_session(exception=None):
        db.session.close()
        db.session.remove()
        db.session.rollback()


    return app
```

The view being tested is as follows

```
@blogs.route('/delete_post/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def delete_post(id):
    """
    Delete a post from the database
    """
    # check if user is logged in
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return redirect(url_for('other.home'))

    post = Post.query.get(id)
    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()

    # redirect to the home page
    return redirect(url_for('other.home'))
```

The changes that were made from the code in the question is as follows.

1. db_session was replaced with db.session
2. The database.py file was made to only initiate a blank Flask-SQLAlchemy instance
3. The setup of the tests were made to use the create_app function defined in init. The testing configuration was passed to it so it uses the test database. Then the db.drop_all and db.create_all Flask-SQLAlchemy functions were used to create and clean out the database.
4. The login and logout was added to the setup and teardown for the tests but that is unrelated to the original question.

What fixed the problem was to change the code to use Flask-SQLAlchemy instead of only SQLAlchemy.